# Find matrix $A$ that solve $Au = v$ for every $x$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $u = (2x+1,x^2+1,2x^2-x)^T , v = (1,x-1,x^2-1)^T$

Find matrix $A$ that solves $Au = v$ for every $x$

Well, I don't know how to find that matrix $A$, any hint of how it is found will be much much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the first row of matrix $A$ be $(a,b,c).$

Then $a,b,c$ will have to satisfy

$$a(2x+1)+b(x^2+1)+c(2x^2-x)=1$$

By comparing coefficient, you should be able to solve for $a,b,c$.

Do the same thing for the other two rows.

Comment: I think it is supposed to be $a + b(x-1) + c(x^2 -1) = 2x+1$ for first row then.

Comment: I wrote $u,v$ vise versa here than what is written. You're correct. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the square matrix **$U$** whose columns are the vector $ u$
evaluated at three different values of $x$ , and similarly for **$V$**.
$$
{\bf U} = \left\| {\,u(x_{\,1} ),u(x_{\,2} ),\,u(x_{\,3} )\;} \right\|
$$
$$
{\bf V} = \left\| {\,v(x_{\,1} ),v(x_{\,2} ),\,v(x_{\,3} )\;} \right\|
$$
then you shall have:
$$
{\bf A}\,{\bf U} = {\bf V}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad {\bf A}\, = {\bf V}\;{\bf U}^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} 
$$

You can verify that the determinant of **$U$** is not null, for whatever $x_{\,1}  \ne x_{\,2}  \ne x_{\,3} $.
Thus choice three “easy” values of $x$ (e.g: $-1,0,1$) and compute **$A$** as per above. It will be valid for whichever $x$.